# varnishlog command not work in ubuntu

Tags: varnish

anyone who can help me? I use ubuntu 12 in VMware. and This command varnishlog doesn't work. When I type in 'varnishlog', the system hanging there for infinite time. 'varnish' command looks good and the configuration file is default. I also try to use sudo ahead of varnishlog, still not work.

Comment: And what about other varnish commands ? Like varnishncsa, varnishstat ?

Comment: i am also facing the same problem , only the varnishreload and varnishstat are working ,and no other command are working.